# Как сделать несколько фильтраций для запуска джабы в Jenkins через generic webhook triger

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, devops, непрерывная-интеграция, webhook

только начал изучать devops, поэтому, возможно, вопрос глупый

Есть джаба на Jenkins, есть репозиторий на BitBucket, там настроен webhook с этой джабой
Сделал фильтрацию в поле optional filter для определенных веток, т.е. когда в этих ветках есть изменения, то джаба запускается
Но мне нужно добавить еще один фильтр, который бы смотрел, что пул реквест открыт

Вопрос - как это сделать? Могу ли я передать несколько значений в поля optional filtr? Если да, то как? Или есть другой вариант?

Спасибо